# help with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have this html block:

```
<p><strong>this is the title</strong>this is the content</p>
```

how do i get only the "this is the content" string with jQuery?

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:** http://jsfiddle.net/mTn7G/

```
var text = $('p').contents().last().text();
```

The [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method gets all child elements, including text nodes, while [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) will give you the last one, and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will return its text content.